# Which loss function does the maximum likelihood estimator minimize?

Tags: bayesian, estimation, parameter-estimation

I'm trying to understand Maximum Likelihood estimators in the context of general estimation theory. I know Bayesian estimator minimizes mean squared loss, MAP estimator minimizes all-or-nothing loss (loss is zero if the estimator estimates the correct parameter and 1 otherwise). Which loss function does the maximum likelihood function minimize?

My thought was that it is negative of the log-liklihood function but the definition of the loss function includes an estimator $T(X)$ and parameter $s$. As I see it, the negative of the log-likelihood function does not have any estimator in it.

Comment: I think I misinterpreted your question so I have deleted my answer.  I thought you were asking about the properties of an estimator of "which outcome has the highest likelihood" whereas now it sounds like you're talking about an estimator of "what is the maximum likelihood of some given outcome".

Comment: In short, in all text books I have gone through, people start estimation theory (in particular point estimators) from defining a loss function and after that a risk function. For example, you have a clear loss function and a corresponding risk function when we talk about minimax, MAP, Bayesian estimators. I'm unable to find any such loss function and corresponding risk function for ML estimators.

Comment: The description maximum likelihood estimator says to me it's a function that finds the most likely outcome. The loss function of such a function is the probability of not matching the actual outcome. This is only meaningful if the probability of any given outcome is nonzero, i.e. in the case of a discrete distribution. In a continuous distribution you have zero probability of matching the outcome exactly so the loss function is constantly probability $1$. Maybe that's why there's no loss function.

Comment: @RobertFrost Your idea makes sense. I was thinking on it from another perspective now. MAP estimator minimizes one-zero loss function. So, ML should also minimize one-zero loss function with additional constraint of no prior (I'm not sure if we can call it uniform prior that is why written no prior). One-zero loss function (both for continuous and discrete case) seems similar to your intuition in the case of discrete case. For both the loss functions, please see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/329908/under-the-0-1-loss-function-the-bayesian-estimator-is-the-mode-of-the-posterior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kullback-Leibler divergence (between the empirical and theoretical probability distributions) is the loss function minimized by the MLE, at least according to this [derivation](https://www.hongliangjie.com/2012/07/12/maximum-likelihood-as-minimize-kl-divergence/), which looks legitimate on first glance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are a bit confused about **risk functions** and **likelihood functions**, so I'll do my best to clear this out.

For a given **likelihood function** $\mathcal L\left(\theta;x_1,\ldots,x_N\right)$, the maximum likelihood estimator yields the estimate $\hat\theta$ that better explains your set of observations $\{x_1,\ldots,x_N\}$ given the statistical model you assumed for each $x_n$ (with $n=1,\ldots,N$). For instance, if each $x_n$ is independent and $x_n \sim \mathcal{N} \left(\theta,1\right)$ ($\forall n$), then your MLE is

\begin{equation}\hat\theta=\frac{1}{N}\sum\limits_{n=1}^N x_n \ . \end{equation}

However, maybe you know *a priori* that you are only interested in solutions that lie within the range $\theta\in[a,b]$ (i.e. "hit or miss" the range $[a,b]$). And that's when the Bayesian philosophy comes in play. The **risk function** is a mechanism for you to add prior knowledge about $\theta$ to the design of your estimator, and the particular shape of the risk function you pick will determine your Bayesian estimator. For the "hit or miss" risk function, for instance, the Bayesian estimator simply asks you to pick the mode of your *a posteriori* PDF, i.e. the *most likely value* according to the *a posteriori* PDF.

To tie the two concepts together, notice that in the first scenario we are implicitly assuming that each $\theta\in\mathbf R$ is equally likely to occur. This means that, for a given model statistical, the Bayesian estimator coincides with the MLE for a uniform prior distribution.

PS: For a more in depth discussion check Chapters 10 and 11 of the first volume (called "Estimation Theory") of "Fundamentals of Statistical Signal Processing" by Steven M. Kay.